# How to run nohup command in mesos without spanning multiple jobs

Tags: marathon, mesosphere

I'm trying to run a one script file in mesos in background by using nohup command trying, but unfortunately the problem is the script executing successfully but the same scripts spanning as multiple jobs and running all jobs in background.

How can I handle the jobs with out spanning multi jobs, restrict a single jobs after scaling the application in marathon.

```
**marathon_sample.json**

{
  "id": "/dps/sample",
  "cmd": "nohup sh /tmp/marathon_test/marathon_sample.sh & >> /tmp/marathon_test/marathon_test.log",
  "cpus": 0.1,
  "mem": 512,
  "disk": 1,
  "instances": 0,
  "container": null,
  "constraints": [
    [
      "hostname",
      "LIKE",
      "(lltws0gbeot.sdi.corp.bankofamerica.com)"
    ]
  ],
  "portDefinitions": [
    {
      "port": 0,
      "protocol": "tcp",
      "name": null,
      "labels": null
    }
  ]
}

**marathon_sample.sh**

#! /bin/sh
while [ true ] ;
do
echo 'Hello Marathon test application'
sleep 5 ;
done
```

Can any one help me to run "marathon_sample.sh" in mesos as a background job.

Answer (score 1):

What's the point of running `nohup` in Marathon? Marathon (resp. Mesos) is supposed to be the "init system" responsible for keeping your job alive and running. You should simplify the command to:

```
"cmd": "sh /tmp/marathon_test/marathon_sample.sh",
```

Logs from `stdout` and `stderr` are automatically being stored into task's workdir. There's no point to write out of your workdir.

Comment: yes thanks, I understood the concept and tried to run without nohup. Working fine for me.